# Property update withing of MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've created an example based on MVVM
Main window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="LearnMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearnMVVM"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="operationTypeEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:OperationType"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeUserControlViewModel}">
            <local:SomeUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=A, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="+" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="0,4,0,5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2"  Text="{Binding Path=B, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Content="Посчитать" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" IsReadOnly="True"  Text="{Binding Path=Summa, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SomeUserControl.Operation, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource operationTypeEnum}}" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" Content="{Binding Path=SomeUserControl}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML of the SomeUserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LearnMVVM.SomeUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:learnMvvm="clr-namespace:LearnMVVM"
             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <learnMvvm:SomeUserControlViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path=A, Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{Binding Path=Operation, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path=B, Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="=" Margin="20" Command="{Binding CalculateOperationComamnd, Mode=TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" Content="{Binding Path=Result, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel of the SomeCustomUserControl:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace LearnMVVM
{
    public enum OperationType
    {
        Sum,
        Sub,
        Div,
        Mul
    }

    public class SomeUserControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }

        //Команды
        private ICommand calculateOperationCommand;
        public ICommand CalculateOperationComamnd 
        {
            get
            {
                return calculateOperationCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                if (calculateOperationCommand != value)
                {
                    calculateOperationCommand = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CalculateOperationComamnd");
                }
            } 
        }

        private OperationType operation;
        public OperationType Operation
        {
            get
            {
                return operation;
            }

            set
            {
                if (operation != value)
                {
                    operation = value;
                    switch (operation)
                    {
                        case OperationType.Sum:
                            CalculateOperationComamnd = new RelayCommand(arg => OperationSum());
                            break;
                        case OperationType.Sub:
                            CalculateOperationComamnd = new RelayCommand(arg => OperationSub());
                            break;
                        case OperationType.Div:
                            CalculateOperationComamnd = new RelayCommand(arg => OperationDiv());
                            break;
                        case OperationType.Mul:
                            CalculateOperationComamnd = new RelayCommand(arg => OperationMul());
                            break;
                    }
                    OnPropertyChanged("Operation");
                }
            }
        }

        private void OperationSum()
        {
            Result = A + B;
        }

        private void OperationSub()
        {
            Result = A - B;
        }

        private void OperationDiv()
        {
            Result = A/B;
        }

        private void OperationMul()
        {
            Result = A*B;
        }

        private double result;
        public double Result
        {
            get { return result; }
            set
            {
                if (Math.Abs(result - value) > 0.0001)
                {
                    result = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Result");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Problem: the custom control does not change, when i'm changing selected item from the combo box and the "calculate button has no effect.

Actually all properties within of SomeCustomControlViewModel are updated as expected, but there is no effect in the main windows.

Have i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Operation` is not a property of `SomeUserControl`. It is a property of `SomeUserControl`'s viewmodel -- reachable as the control's `DataContext`. Try binding `ComboBox.SelectedItem` like so:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SomeUserControl.DataContext.Operation, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

The change is that I added `DataContext` to the path.

This is why you don't use viewmodels with custom controls, if you really want to use them as controls. You write a control class deriving from `Control`, and give it dependency properties. `Operation` should be a dependency property of a class derived from `Control`, not a notifying property on a viewmodel. Then you define UI for it by applying a `ControlTemplate` via a default `Style`.

What you've got here is really a child viewmodel. With that type of arrangement, ordinarily the parent viewmodel would provide an instance of the child viewmodel, and bind it to the child control itself. Then anybody who wanted to use a property of the child viewmodel would bind `ChildVM.WhateverProperty`.

Comment: Thank you! There was one more issue - SomeUserControl was defined as SomeUserControlViewModel, I've changed it to SomeUserControl and now it works as expected.